# Generating POJO instances from Json

Tags: java, json, pojo

Is there a lib to create POJO instance from Json ?

Actually I'm using [JJSchema](https://github.com/reinert/JJSchema) to generate a full Json from the POJO but I can't find to do the reverse.

PS : My POJO is have other POJOs as attributes.

Comment: I think any lib can do that, try GSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give [FasterXML Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) a try. In my opinion it is very straight forward and easy to use.
Here's the example from the github page that describes how a Java Object can be created from JSON

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // create once, reuse
MyValue value = mapper.readValue(new File("data.json"), MyValue.class);
// or:
value = mapper.readValue(new URL("http://some.com/api/entry.json"), MyValue.class);
// or:
value = mapper.readValue("{\"name\":\"Bob\", \"age\":13}", MyValue.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this site to Generate Plain Old Java Objects `POJO` from `JSON` or `JSON-Schemay`.

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: I've already tried this but it generates the class and not an object instance !